# VOIP/Skype/GoogleVoice solution without a PC

Tags: skype, voip, voice, phone

In short, I'm looking to drop current VOIP provider (Cablevision/Optimum Voice) and go with cheaper standalone package BUT want to keep existing standard phone that plugs into their box.

Does anyone know of any solution, preferably Skype, Google Voice etc, that I can switch to but without the need for a go-between computer?

*Side note: Vonage have a $9.99 per month plan that might work, but will Vonage be around next year?*

**UPDATE:** TO clarify a little more: I know I could use an Android/iPhone with a Skype app etc over wifi but we find the there is a large difference in quality/volume between an actual landline phone (even over voip) and a cellphone. With out current handset its already to go with a charger etc while Android/iPhone requires dock. The priority is to use an existing handset. Second, I do not want yet another computer in the house, that will require restarts, plugging into another socket and such. Thanks so far for suggestions, please keep them coming.

Answer (score 2):

I've got a Linksys PAP2 which I use for British Telecom SIP VoIP.  You could use one with Vonage, without having to need to turn your computer on.  They are very cheap on eBay.

There are also various Skype phones available on their website.  I can only seem to link to the UK site [here](http://shop.skype.com/intl/en-gb/phones/).

Comment: Thank you. I'll investigate that. as for Skype phones I want to avoid anything that is service specific or requires getting me a new handset. In-between hardware (like the PAP2) is fine, just want to plug in any phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Voice with push notifications and such on the Android, Blackberry, and iPhone smartphone systems...Android and Blackberry have more integrated apps than the iPhone...

Sorry, after the reading the question more thoroughly, I realized that you wanted to *keep* your standard phone and use it - sorry...you could always switch to a smartphone, and ditch the landline...FWIW....